# PHP explode to retrieve delimited text

Tags: php, explode

I have an assignment that asks me to retrieve delimited text from form values. The text is delimited with an asterisk (`*`). I have been trying to use the `explode()` function to do this, but I'm not having any luck. Here is my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Bills</title>
<style>
body {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.bad {
color:#FF0000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My Bills</h1>

<?php 

echo "
<p><strong>Sort Order for Items:</strong> 
<form method='post'>";

$choice = $_POST['sort'];

if ($choice == 'ascending')
    echo "
<label for='ascending'>Ascending</label><input name='sort' type='radio' id='ascending' value='ascending' checked='checked' /> 

<label for='descending'>Descending</label><input name='sort' type='radio' value='descending' id='descending' />";

if ($choice == 'descending')
    echo "
<label for='ascending'>Ascending</label><input name='sort' type='radio' id='ascending' value='ascending' /> 

<label for='descending'>Descending</label><input name='sort' type='radio' value='descending' id='descending' checked='checked' />";

if ($choice == '')
    echo "
<label for='ascending'>Ascending</label><input name='sort' type='radio' id='ascending' value='ascending' checked='checked'  /> 

<label for='descending'>Descending</label><input name='sort' type='radio' value='descending' id='descending' />";

echo "
<table border='0' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='5'>
  <tr>
    <td><h4>Item</h4></td>
    <td><h4>Amount</h4></td>
  </tr>
";

for($row=1; $row<5;$row++)
    {

    $item_name='item_name'.$row;    
    $item_value = $_POST[$item_name];

    $amount_name='amount_name'.$row;    
    $amount_value = $_POST[$amount_name];


    $myelement = "$item_value*$amount_value*";
    $myarray = array($myelement);
    array_push($myarray, $myelement); //Adds $myelement to the end of the $myarray array
    foreach ($myarray as $myName)
    {
    $list = explode("*", $myName);
    echo "<br>".$list[0];
    }

echo 
"<tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='$item_name' value='$item_value'  /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='$amount_name' value='$amount_value' /></td>
";  

    if (!empty($amount_value))
    {
            if(is_numeric($amount_value))
            {
            $total = $total + $amount_value;
            }
            else {
        echo    
            "<td class='bad'>Amount Invalid: $amount_value</td>";
            $error_count++;
            }
    }


echo"   
  </tr>
";

    }
echo " 

<tr>
    <td colspan='2'>
    <input name='' type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </td>
</table>
    ";
    if ($error_count > 0)
    {
    echo "<br /><span class='bad' />Errors: $error_count</span>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<br />Total: $total";
    }


?>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, but even so I doubt the problem lies with the explode function. If the rest is correct, you should use explode like this: `$list = explode('*', ...); print_r($list);`

Comment: It's better if you ask us how to solve your homework instead of this.

Comment: I added in the full code to try and make what I'm doing clearer. Basically I need to take the values that were entered into the text field, store them all in an array, delimited by an *, then output them back into the text fields either starting in the top fields or the bottom fields, which depends on whether or not a user selected "Ascending" or "Descending". I hope this is a little clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your crazy code do, but this is proper syntax:

```
$list = explode("*", $sort_line[$array_counter]);
echo "<br>".$list[0];
```

or

```
list($list) = explode("*", $sort_line[$array_counter]);
echo "<br>".$list;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

And i suppose you should change `$sort_line[$array_counter]` to `$myName`

Comment: What's the point of using the list construct when you're not unpacking anything?

Comment: I tried doing this and it seemed to work, except the value after the * isn't showing, just the first one is.

Comment: `$list` is an array so printfirst element `echo "<br>".$list[0];` and second element of `$list` array `echo "<br>".$list[1];` More info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is a homework question, I’ll try to give you some hints to think about your own code. Also I’m actually a bit unsure what exactly you were trying to do:

- If you want to run `explode()` on the form values, why are you concatenating the values with a `*` first?
- Why do you put those values into an array, i.e. what should the array be for?
- Take a look at your `array()` call and check what you are doing directly below. Do you want the values to be in there twice?
- Within the foreach loop, what is `$sort_line`, and what is `$array_counter`? Those variables are undefined.
- Also think about the placement of the foreach loop. It is within the outer for loop, so it does executed with each item, you are reading from `$_POST`. Is that really what you want?
- `explode()` returns an array of the elements you split from the string. `list()` unpacks an array into concrete variables. You probably want to print out the unpacked values, right?